# JQUERY sortable plugin, inititate function when the draggable element hovers a specified one

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-sortable

How can inititate function when the draggable element hovers a specified one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#event-stop . Under events, check out the stop event. It fires when you stop moving the mouse.

**UPDATE**

Try [jQuery hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) on the element you want to react to the hover.

Comment: I don't want this to happen when the mouse stops :( that could cause problems. Just as soon as the element hovers :)

Comment: Perhaps I misinterpreted the documentation. I presumed the stop event triggered when the mouse stopped moving, but the mouse button was still depressed. In that case, you can use the jQuery `hover` event on the DOM element you want to react to a hover.

Comment: Hey Jwatts, maybe my question was abit unclear, I would like a function to be initiated when the element I am dragging hovers the specified element, not the mouse :)